# Finding k elements with count queries

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, it.information-theory

Given a 'count in range' query access to an array of $N$ elements, our goal is to find $K$ missing elements with as few queries as possible (worst case, deterministic).

To clarify, we can query

> how many missing elements are in range $[i, j]$?

for any $0\leq i\leq j<N.$

It's easy to see that we can accomplish this task with $K \log N$ queries (simply using binary search for each of the $K$ elements). But our query potentially returns $\log K$ bits of information. Can we do better?

Any reference is appreciated. Thank you good people!

Comment: do you know the range of the elements in the array? are the elements sorted? this question seems under-specified

Comment: @kodlu As I interpret it, the elements in the array are either "missing" or "not missing" in some unknown order and we have to find the missing ones.

Comment: Of course using $N$ queries is faster if $K$ is very large, but apart from that I suspect $K\log n$ is optimal.  Suppose $N=K^2$ and you are told in advance that each of the $K$ segments of length $K$ contains one target. It takes $\Theta(K\log K)=\Theta(K\log n)$ queries to find them if the queries are restricted to within segments. I don't think it helps to use queries overlapping segments as that just gives you linear equations with no greater dimension than the number of equations. It would take a some effort to turn this into a solid proof.